# How do you get rsync to load a list of (full rules, not limited like --include-from) filter rules from a file?

Tags: rsync

`rsync` has various options for reading various config from files so that you don't have to chain a bunch of individual `--include` or `--exclude` options together. All of these options (as far as I cantell) read from a file on your *local* computer:

       `--exclude-from=FILE
       --include-from=FILE
       --files-from=FILE`

The doc for `--files-from=FILE` even clarifies that you can use it with either a local or remote FILE:

> In  addition,  the  --files-from file can be read from the remote host instead of the local host if you specify a "host:" in
>   front of the file (the host must match one end of the transfer).  As a
>   short-cut, you can specify just a prefix of ":" to mean "use the
>   remote end of the transfer".

What I'm wondering is where or what is the equivalent for `--filter`? We have `--include` and `--include-from`; `--exclude`  and `--exclude-from`. But **where's `--filter-from`?** (Or what's the closest equivalent to it?)

The section on **INCLUDE/EXCLUDE PATTERN RULES** gives examples of using a list of pattern rules as if they were included in a file...

```
          + /some/
          + /some/path/
          + /some/path/this-file-is-found
          + /file-also-included
          - *
```

but the only mention I could find of using them in a file is with a file loaded from a `merge` or `dir-merge`:

```
          merge, . specifies a merge-file to read for more rules.
          dir-merge, : specifies a per-directory merge-file.
```

I couldn't find any mention of whether that refers to a merge-file on the local or remote hosts, but from what I've tried so far, it seems to only work with a file on the *remote* host.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's exactly the option:

```
rsync --filter "merge /some/filterlist.conf"
```

*(Note how `-F` is an alias to `--filter "dir-merge /.rsync-filter"`.)*

`merge` files are read from the *local* (client) system (unless you explicitly pass the option to the server using `-M`). If the source is remote, all filter rules are automatically sent to it.

Meanwhile `dir-merge` is always applied to the *source*, whether local or not. (Manual page: "These per-directory rule files must be created on the sending side because it is the sending side that is being scanned for the available files to transfer.")

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @grawity! I finally had a chance to test it out and found that you are right about `merge`, which makes me very happy. It turns out my problem had more to do with needing to include the full absolute path in my merge-file. Once I fixed that issue, the `--filter "merge merge-file"` option worked beautifully. :)

Comment: That totally makes sense now what you said about a `dir-merge` is always applied to the _source_, whether local or not. Bonus points for showing where that is documented in the man page.

I'm curious, though: Did you actually find anything in the manual that would have clarified that "`merge` files are read from the _local_ (client) system" or is that just from experience? (I still can't find it in the manual)

Comment: That's nice how they have `-F` as an alias for `--filter "dir-merge /.rsync-filter"`. Now they just need to add `--filter-from=FILE` as an alias for `--filter "merge FILE"` to give it an easier-to-use (and more obvious) shortcut for loading a *local* merge file, and for parity with `--include-from=FILE` and `--files-from=FILE`! :)

Comment: @TylerRick in the manual section it is written "The  filter  rules  allow for flexible selection of which files to transfer (include) and which files to skip (exclude)." I think this means that filter rules are applied to the source (be it local or remote). For `merge` that would be the same and I think that you are right. However, a test would be good for the final answer.